# If all gameObjects in list meet a condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I check if all gameObjects in a list meet a certain condition in Unity? I have 9 colliders with the same script. They all have a list, which changes through
I tried this code, but it returns weird results.

```
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ChildTiles.Count; i++) 
    {
        if (ChildTiles [i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color == Green) 
        {
            _greenComplete = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            _greenComplete = false;
        }
        //Debug.Log (gameObject + "ChildTiles[i]" + ChildTiles [i]);
    }
    Debug.Log (gameObject + "Green Complete " + _greenComplete);
}
```

The weird thing is that the top-right collider returns True, with two gameObjects with a green color and the bottom-right collider returns false, with two gameObjects with a green color.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/cb3352585720e2e630315a268a436fb6.png]

This it the inspector of the top-right collider during this result:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/aa210144daf5fb663292fff1fa198b27.png]

This is the inspector of the bottom-right collider during this result:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/97ad742e723a31dddea7ab43eaf8e31a.png]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Another nice question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from your `for` loop. Look closely at what you have written. For every element of your list, you are checking if the color of its SpriteRenderer component is green. If that is the case, you set `_greenComplete` to true, else you set it to false.

Now let's look at your two lists and try to use this algorithm on each one. For the first list:

- The first element is yellow. `_greenComplete` is set to false.
- The second element is green. `_greenComplete` is set to true.
- The third element is red. `_greenComplete` is set to false.
- The fourth element is green. `_greenComplete` is set to true.

Do you see where the problem is now? You are not defining if your list contains a green element. You are successively defining if the last analyzed element is green. As we just saw for your first list, at the end, the final result is true because the last element of your list is green. Looking at your second list:

- The first element is green. `_greenComplete`is set to true.
- The second element is green. `_greenComplete` is set to true.
- The third element is red. `_greenComplete` is set to false.
- The fourth element is yellow. `_greenComplete` is set to false.

Your list contained two green elements, but the last analyzed element was not green, leading to the false value you get at the end.

To fix your code and get the real answer you want, you rather go for a `while` loop, which will stop as soon as you find a green element different that is not green in your list (you start assuming that every elements are green indeed green, and check if it is not the case):

```
void Update()
{
    int i = 0;
    _greenComplete = true;

    while(i < ChildTiles.Count && _greenComplete) 
    {
        if (ChildTiles [i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color != Green) 
        {
            _greenComplete = false;
        } 

        i++;
    }

    Debug.Log (gameObject + "Green Complete " + _greenComplete);
}
```

You can also use LINQ for this matter:

```
_greenComplete  = ChildTiles.All (c => c.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color == Green);
```

Comment: This returns True even if there is only one green Object inside the list.

Comment: Ok I am using this code right now: https://pastebin.com/0u2EH6iT. It wait till the rotation is done, and then it checks if there is a match of 4 colors. The problem right now is that when every color is matched, it only returns True when you click on the button which checks if the colors are matched. Why is that? Here is a gif to understand it better: https://gyazo.com/a2a5c8a5051e937338807fb5ecfaa4ec

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn Ah, so you want every color to match, I didn't undertand it from your question. I edited my answer for this matter then.
For your other problem, it's hard to know just with this piece of code. You should probably do the test every time after making your squares rotate.

Comment: But thats what I am doing already, cause it waits for 1 seconds and the rotation is taking 0.5 seconds. The problem is that it only check the last clicked collider.

Comment: What does ChildTiles contain exactly?

Comment: ChildTIles is the list attachted to each collider (behind each button). The list contains the 4 tiles around the collider.

Comment: Then here is the problem. Your whole grid is not verified, only the 4 tiles around your button. You should instead call a function which checks if all the squares are full with the good colors.

Comment: But how do I do that?

Comment: That is a different question from the one in this thread though, so you should close this one and open a new one I think. But to give you an idea, I would have an object referencing all the cases on your board, and in the code I would make a loop which checks for every pair of 2 x 2 items if their color match. If every pairs are answering true, then it means your board is complete.

Comment: Isn't it possible to edit your answer, instead of me making another thread? This is the fourth thread from me about this question.. It would help me a lot.

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn One thread is about one problem. That's not a thing on SO to suddenly change the question to transform it into something else, so I'm sorry about that. Plus, I miss a lot of code information to actually be able to help you on the point you are asking, making it impossible to give you a proper answer here.